# Скролинг к блоку по середине экрана

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне требуется осуществить скролинг к блоку при нажатии на ссылку, на просторах интернета нашел плагин jQuery.ScrollTo.
Проблема заключается в том, что я и подключил плагин и по примерам сделал переход туда - куда мне требуется, но почему то вместо срабатывания скрипта происходит дефолтный переход по метке, причем блок появляется приклееным к верху

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#oneclick').click(function() {
    jQuery.scrollTo('#one');
});
});
</script>

<ul class="soderz" >
<li><a href="#oneclick">Почему мы?</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="preim" id="one">
....
</div>
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Ты забыл `return false;`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#oneclick').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo('#one');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. А как собственно сделать чтобы блок был по середине экрана а не к верху приклеен?

Comment: @Дмитрий, а при чём тут расположение блока? К нему в любом случае будет скроллиться.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я видимо не правильно выразился, мне требуется чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, проскролило к блоку, но нужно, чтобы сверху и снизу блока было одинаковое расстояние(блок это линия высотой 600 пикселей) сама страница является лендингом.